# How could i get my intern computer audio in real time?

Tags: python, audio

Ok so i would like to make a program that listen my computer audio in real time, and when it says some word what i defined as important it alerts me... (the code is in python), I used the speech recognition

I tried this code but it just get my microphone audio:

````py
import speech_recognition as sr
from playsound import playsound

def capt():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        final = ''

        cont = 0

        print(':')

        while True:
            if cont == 10:
                final = ''
            with sr.Microphone() as fonte:
                audio = r.listen(fonte)
                cont = 0
                try:
                    text = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'pt-BR')
                    final += f' {text}'
                except:
                    print('Error')
                else: 
                    print('✔️')
            div = final.split(' ')
            if 'Special' in div:
                playsound("som/alarme.mp3") # it plays an alarm
                final = ''
                div = ''


            cont += 1```
````

Comment: Please make your question more specific: 
- what did you try?
- post some coding attempts.

Comment: Sorry i tried to make my question cleaner